# How can I extract a DataTable from a ReportDataSource

Tags: c#, datatable, ssrs-2008, datasource

I am trying to export the underlying data of my report to excelsheet. 
I have ReportDataSource. I need to access the DataTable in this DataSource. I am trying this by:

```
        IReportViewModel rptViewModel = m_CurrentReport;
        queryDatatable = (DataTable)rptViewModel.GetReportDataSources().GetValue(0);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The excel button is clicked.");
```

I get the following error:

Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Please help me in solving this error.

Comment: what have you assigned to report data source?

Comment: @NoOne The report datasource has a DataTable. Which i have assigned in a viewModel.

Comment: @voonna `ReportDataSource` is something we put data into not pull data from it. You should reference the actual/original datasource to get the data you want.

Comment: @KingKing By any chance can we do the reverse engineering? to get to access the DataTable from it?

Comment: @voonna a `ReportDataSource` keeps a reference to the source you passed in its constructor in the property `Value`, see my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
queryDatatable = (DataTable)((ReportDataSource)rptViewModel.GetReportDataSources().GetValue(0)).Value;
```

Comment: The property (.Value) dosn't exist. So that is not working. :(

Comment: @voonna what is the type of `.GetValue(0)`?

Comment: rptViewModel.GetReportDataSources().GetValue(0).GetType(); returns {Name = "ReportDataSource" FullName = "Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

Comment: @voonna it looks like it's exactly a `ReportDataSource`, so it should have the property `Value`.

Comment: @voonna OK, it's in fact a `ReportDataSource` but referenced by an `object` (maybe), so we have to cast it to `ReportDataSource`, just updated my answer.